# How do I set up proper ownership of these files?

Tags: permissions, group, read-write

I need the directory `/var/www/` (and everything inside it) to be modifiable by only authorized users.

The way I tried to do this was:

```
sudo groupadd webmasters
sudo usermod -G webmasters pi # My user is pi
sudo chown -R root:webmasters /var/www/
sudo chmod -R ug+rw /var/www/
```

...but I can't modify anything in `/var/www/`, nor can I create new files in it.

What am I doing wrong? How do I set this up the way it needs to be?

What I'm envisioning is:

- Everyone in the group `webmasters` can create, delete, and edit files in `/var/www/`
- All newly-created files/folders are owned by `root:webmasters`
- All newly created files have permissions 775: `-rwxrwxr-x`
- Is is *vital* that **no one** without authorization be able to have write permissions, OR any sort of Setuid/Setgid ability. (Authorization for write access can only be granted by Root.)

Am I taking the wrong approach to this? Do I have the right idea, but I'm just messing something up? What's going wrong?

Comment: Output of `getent group webmasters` is `webmasters:x:1005:pi`, so I know I'm *in* the group...

Comment: Have you logged in again after adding yourself to the group? The kernel's process management doesn't care about changes to `/etc/groups` after a process has been created and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that a user's been added to a group in the `/etc/group` file through the `usermod -G` command. This updates the "database" but any shells/processes that have been already created prior to this update will not reflect that the user that owns them, `pi`, has been added to this new group.

Usually you don't want to use the `getent` commands when interrogating a shell, but rather the command `id`, or more specifically `id -a`.

#### example

Here I've just added my username `saml` to the group `newgrp`. The command `getent` confirms this:

```
$ getent group newgrp
newgrp:x:10000:saml
```

But the command `id -a` tells a different story in one of the shells that I already had open:

```
$ id -a
uid=500(saml) gid=501(saml) groups=501(saml),502(vboxusers),503(jupiter)
```

If I start up a new shell I'll see `newgrp`:

```
$ ssh localhost
Last login: Fri Jun 28 00:17:13 2013 from localhost.localdomain

$ id -a
uid=500(saml) gid=501(saml) groups=501(saml),502(vboxusers),503(jupiter),10000(newgrp)
```

Comment: Awesome! Logging out, then in, fixed the permissions! Now to set default ownership of newly-created files...

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - I believe your approach is fine, you just needed to logout/in to get the group to show up so you'd have permissions.